# How can I use a WCF with a SSL Certificate HTTPS IIS

Tags: asp.net, wcf, web, service

I have a couple days trying to fix a problem with my WCF that do work when the Bindings are HTTP. But once I buy a SSL certificate and I configure my website to work in HTTPS, when I changed the bindings on IIS my application has been unavailable.

**I got the following error message:**
 `Could not find a base address that matches scheme http for the endpoint with binding WebHttpBinding. Registered base address schemes are [https].`

My web.config

```
<services>
  <service behaviorConfiguration="WebServiceBehavior" name="WcfService1.Service">
    <endpoint address="" behaviorConfiguration="jsonBehavior" binding="webHttpBinding"
              bindingConfiguration="webHttpBindingWithJsonP" contract="WcfService1.IService"/>
    <endpoint address="soap" binding="basicHttpBinding" contract="WcfService1.IService" />
  </service>
</services>

<behaviors>
  <endpointBehaviors>
    <behavior name="jsonBehavior">
      <webHttp helpEnabled="true"/>
    </behavior>
  </endpointBehaviors>

  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="WebServiceBehavior">
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>

<bindings>
  <webHttpBinding>
    <binding name="webHttpBindingWithJsonP"
             crossDomainScriptAccessEnabled="true"   />

  </webHttpBinding>

</bindings>
```

It is possible to get my WCF working with HTTPS ?

Answer (score 0):

Does this help https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh556232(v=vs.110).aspx? It includes a complete config example for https.

In particular I think you need the `security mode=Transport` for SSL to work:

```
<binding name="webHttpBindingWithJsonP" crossDomainScriptAccessEnabled="true">
    <security mode="Transport">
      <transport clientCredentialType="None"/>
    </security>
</binding>
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi **Chris F Carroll**,

Thanks for taking the time to answer to my post.

Finally I could be able to fix it by myself.

**Here is what i did to getting work on HTTPS and HTTP:**

`< serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingEnabled="true" aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="false" />`

The code above goes inside of:

```
<system.serviceModel>
```